# How to expand search bar after presses on search icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am somehow create an Search icon by a component and I just wanna know how to expand search bar icon when someone presses on it..

```
  import { TouchableOpacity,View, Image} from 'react-native';
  import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
  export default class Search extends Component{
     onClick(){
      return <SearchBar/> // [![Seach Image][1]][1]not working
}

render(){
    // not worrking
    let search = <SearchBar/>;
    return(
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    return search
                }}
            >
                <Image
                    source={require('../images/tabs/search.png')}
                    style={{height: 40, width: 60}}
                    resizeMode={'contain'}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
     )
   }
 }
```

[image: SearchImage]

Comment: is this is what you looking for ? https://codesandbox.io/s/3vrly046k5

Comment: @AravindS no what was that...

Comment: its an example showing how to animate the width

Comment: yeah I want icon to expand and take user input..but it covers the header title with it,,,so it looks weird..

Comment: try it with the Animation

Comment: @AravindS can you help me about figuring one thing..see when somone presses button I just want it go below the header or cover the header...All I want is just that..with animation it just animates it not hide the header...I want when user presses button header should hide and  search expand

Comment: Onpress, make a state true and show the search bar over the header..use conditional operation for this..use search animation for this purpose

Comment: @AravindS how can I use conditional operations here..                                
         const Inside = TabNavigator({ Home:{  screen: Home,                                                                                 
                                                          navigationOptions: { headerLeft: null,
                                                         headerTitle: "Blue Rocker",
                                                        headerRight: <HeaderImage/>, } }})

Answer (score 1):

You should add a state to your component to control the behaviour of the header

```
import { TouchableOpacity, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
export default class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      showSearchBar: false, // control what ever to render the searchbar or just the icon
    };
  }
  onClick() {
    let { showSearchBar } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      showSearchBar: !showSearchBar,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { showSearchBar } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        {!showSearchBar ? (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onClick}>
            <Image
              source={require('../images/tabs/search.png')}
              style={{ height: 40, width: 60 }}
              resizeMode={'contain'}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
          <SearchBar />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It says undefined is not an object (evaluating this.state.showSearchBar)

Comment: bind the onClick method to save the context

Comment: it worked but looking little weird..if i want to search through every item I have how to do I it pal..

Comment: it is all related to the state so render your items from the state and then when typing inside the search bar just filter the items and change the state with result of the filter. I my give you a more precise answer if you ask an other question.

Comment: I did pal ..I asked another question on stack overflow, how to search through items..can you make it more clear what you said..help would be really appreciated

Comment: I meant to ask an other stackoverflow question in other thread an comment the link here ... and if the solution i suggest answer this question please check it